# Почему кнопки не реагируют?

Tags: python, многопоточность, pyqt, qt-designer, qthread

При нажатии кнопки **`"start"`** должен запускаться цикл, а при нажатии на кнопку **`"stop"`** соответственно останавливаться.

Можно по другому реализовать, главное чтобы работало.

**main.py**

```
import sys
import os
import sqlite3
from threading import Thread
from PyQt5.Qt import *
from des import *
import socket, struct

class MyWin(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtWidgets.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

        params = True

        self.ui.tableWidget.horizontalHeader().setSectionResizeMode(QHeaderView.ResizeToContents)
        self.ui.tableWidget.horizontalHeader().setMinimumSectionSize(0)

        self.table_index = 0
        self.row_count = 1

        #Подключение к БД

        sqlite_connection = sqlite3.connect("New.db")
        cursor = sqlite_connection.cursor()

        sqlite_select_query = """SELECT ip FROM ips"""
        cursor.execute(sqlite_select_query)
        records = cursor.fetchall()

        # Перебор ip адресов

        for row in records:
            self.ui.tableWidget.setRowCount(self.row_count)
            self.ui.tableWidget.setItem(self.table_index, 0, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(str(row[0])))

            self.table_index += 1
            self.row_count += 1

        cursor.close()
        sqlite_connection.close()

        style_1 = """QTableWidget::item {background-color: white;
                     border-style: outset;
                     border-width: 3px; border-radius: 7px; border-color: red;
                     }"""
        style_2 = """QTableWidget::item {background-color: white;
                     border-style: outset;
                     border-width: 3px; border-radius: 7px; border-color: green;
                     }"""
        self.setStyleSheet(style_1)
# ---------
    @staticmethod
    def pings(self, params):
        while not params:
            for column in range(self.ui.tableWidget.columnCount()):
                for row in range(self.ui.tableWidget.rowCount()):
                    text = str(self.ui.tableWidget.item(row, column).text())
                    
                    response = os.system("ping " + text + " -n 2 -w 100")

class set_ping(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

        self.ui.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.start)
        self.ui.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(self.stop)

    def start(self):
        self.thread = QThread() 
        self.thread.started.connect(self.pings(False))
        self.thread.start()

    def stop(self):
        self.thread = QThread() 
        self.thread.started.connect(self.pings(True))
        self.thread.start()

# ---------


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    myapp = MyWin()
    myapp.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**des.py**

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(589, 431)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.tabWidget = QtWidgets.QTabWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.tabWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 591, 391))
        self.tabWidget.setObjectName("tabWidget")
        self.tab = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.tab.setObjectName("tab")
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.tab, "")
        self.tab_2 = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.tab_2.setObjectName("tab_2")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.tab_2)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(90, 80, 75, 23))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.tab_2)
        self.pushButton_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(170, 80, 75, 23))
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")
        self.plainTextEdit = QtWidgets.QPlainTextEdit(self.tab_2)
        self.plainTextEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 210, 581, 151))
        self.plainTextEdit.setObjectName("plainTextEdit")
        self.tableWidget = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(self.tab_2)
        self.tableWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(450, 10, 131, 191))
        self.tableWidget.setObjectName("tableWidget")
        self.tableWidget.setColumnCount(1)
        self.tableWidget.setRowCount(1)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setVerticalHeaderItem(0, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(0, item)
        self.comboBox = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self.tab_2)
        self.comboBox.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(90, 110, 151, 22))
        self.comboBox.setObjectName("comboBox")
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.tab_2, "")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 589, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        self.menu = QtWidgets.QMenu(self.menubar)
        self.menu.setObjectName("menu")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)
        self.action123 = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.action123.setObjectName("action123")
        self.action123_2 = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.action123_2.setObjectName("action123_2")
        self.menu.addAction(self.action123)
        self.menu.addAction(self.action123_2)
        self.menubar.addAction(self.menu.menuAction())

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        self.tabWidget.setCurrentIndex(1)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.tabWidget.setTabText(self.tabWidget.indexOf(self.tab), _translate("MainWindow", "Мониторинг"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Start"))
        self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Stop"))
        item = self.tableWidget.verticalHeaderItem(0)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "1"))
        item = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(0)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "ip"))
        self.tabWidget.setTabText(self.tabWidget.indexOf(self.tab_2), _translate("MainWindow", "Пинг портов"))
        self.menu.setTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "до"))
        self.action123.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "123"))
        self.action123_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "123"))
```

Comment: В классе set_ping нет метода pings(False)

Comment: @AlexanderChernin но он есть в MyWin

Comment: И что? Это другой класс, а в set_ping вы делаете вызов через connect(self.pings... а что такое self по-вашему?

Comment: И как мне его из этого класса включить ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Обратите внимание:

- ячейка, содержащая `ip` - чекабельная
- проверяются только адреса, в которых флажок не установлен
- для запуска и остановки процесса используется одна и та же кнопка

**main.py**

```
import sys
import os
import sqlite3
#import socket, struct
# from threading import Thread
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.Qt import *


#from des import *
class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(620, 431)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.tabWidget = QtWidgets.QTabWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.tabWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 610, 391))
        self.tabWidget.setObjectName("tabWidget")
        self.tab = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.tab.setObjectName("tab")
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.tab, "")
        self.tab_2 = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.tab_2.setObjectName("tab_2")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.tab_2)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(90, 80, 75, 23))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.tab_2)
        self.pushButton_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(170, 80, 75, 23))
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")
        self.plainTextEdit = QtWidgets.QPlainTextEdit(self.tab_2)
        self.plainTextEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 210, 581, 151))
        self.plainTextEdit.setObjectName("plainTextEdit")
        self.tableWidget = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(self.tab_2)
        self.tableWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(450, 10, 150, 191))
        self.tableWidget.setObjectName("tableWidget")
        self.tableWidget.setColumnCount(1)
        self.tableWidget.setRowCount(1)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setVerticalHeaderItem(0, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(0, item)
        self.comboBox = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self.tab_2)
        self.comboBox.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(90, 110, 151, 22))
        self.comboBox.setObjectName("comboBox")
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.tab_2, "")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 589, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        self.menu = QtWidgets.QMenu(self.menubar)
        self.menu.setObjectName("menu")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)
        self.action123 = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.action123.setObjectName("action123")
        self.action123_2 = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.action123_2.setObjectName("action123_2")
        self.menu.addAction(self.action123)
        self.menu.addAction(self.action123_2)
        self.menubar.addAction(self.menu.menuAction())

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        self.tabWidget.setCurrentIndex(1)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.tabWidget.setTabText(self.tabWidget.indexOf(self.tab), _translate("MainWindow", "Мониторинг"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Start"))
        self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Stop"))
        item = self.tableWidget.verticalHeaderItem(0)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "1"))
        item = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(0)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "ip"))
        self.tabWidget.setTabText(self.tabWidget.indexOf(self.tab_2), _translate("MainWindow", "Пинг портов"))
        self.menu.setTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "до"))
        self.action123.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "123"))
        self.action123_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "123"))
        

# +++ vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
class WorkThread(QtCore.QThread):
    threadSignal = QtCore.pyqtSignal(int, str, tuple)

    def __init__(self, dictIP):
        super().__init__()
        self.dictIP = dictIP

    def run(self):
        for k, v in self.dictIP.items():
            if v[2] == 0:
                response = os.system("ping " + k + " -n 2 -w 100")
                self.msleep(20)
                self.threadSignal.emit(response, k, v)
        self.finished.emit()
# +++ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
 

class MyWin(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtWidgets.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        
        self.ui.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.startThread)
#        self.ui.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(self.stop)                       # ---

        self.thread = None                                                     # +++

        self.ui.tableWidget.horizontalHeader().setSectionResizeMode(QHeaderView.ResizeToContents)
        self.ui.tableWidget.horizontalHeader().setMinimumSectionSize(0)

#        self.table_index = 0
        self.row_count = 1

        #Подключение к БД
#        sqlite_connection = sqlite3.connect("New.db")
        sqlite_connection = sqlite3.connect("News.db")                         # News
        cursor = sqlite_connection.cursor()
#        sqlite_select_query = """SELECT ip FROM ips"""
        sqlite_select_query = """SELECT ip FROM ip"""                          # ip
        cursor.execute(sqlite_select_query)
        records = cursor.fetchall()
        cursor.close()
        sqlite_connection.close()

# +++ vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
        # Перебор ip адресов
        for row, value in enumerate(records):
            self.ui.tableWidget.setRowCount(self.row_count)
            item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(str(value[0]))
            item.setFlags(item.flags() | QtCore.Qt.ItemIsUserCheckable)
            item.setCheckState(QtCore.Qt.Unchecked)
#            self.ui.tableWidget.setItem(self.table_index, 0, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(str(row[0])))
            self.ui.tableWidget.setItem(row, 0, item)
            self.row_count += 1
       
    def startThread(self):
        dictIP = {}
        for row in range(self.ui.tableWidget.rowCount()):
            item = self.ui.tableWidget.item(row, 0)
            if not item.checkState():
                item.setBackground(QtGui.QColor("#edeef7"))
            dictIP[item.text()] = (row, 0, item.checkState())

        if self.thread is None:
            self.thread = WorkThread(dictIP)
            self.thread.threadSignal.connect(self.on_threadSignal)
            self.thread.finished.connect(self.threadFinished)
            self.thread.start()
            self.ui.pushButton.setText("Stop thread")
        else:
            self.thread.terminate()
            self.thread = None
            self.ui.pushButton.setText("Start thread")

    def on_threadSignal(self, response, k, v):
        #print(response, k, v)
        item = self.ui.tableWidget.item(v[0], v[1])
        item.setCheckState(QtCore.Qt.Checked)
        if response:
            item.setBackground(QtGui.QColor("#fa7f72"))
        else:
            item.setBackground(QtGui.QColor("#54e346"))       

    def stop(self):
        pass   

    def threadFinished(self):
        self.thread = None
        self.ui.pushButton.setText("Start thread")
    
# +++ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    myapp = MyWin()
    myapp.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

---

**Скрипт создания и заполнения БД**

```
import sqlite3

# Добавление данных в таблицы

try:
    connect = sqlite3.connect("News.db")
    cursor = connect.cursor()
    print("База данных подключена к SQLite")
    
    cursor.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ip(
                      ip INTEGER);""")

    connect.commit()

    records = [[f"192.168.{i}.9"] for i in range(1, 101)]
    cursor.executemany("insert into ip values(?)", records)
    connect.commit()

    print("Запись успешно добавлена")
    cursor.close()

except sqlite3.Error as error:
    print("Ошибка при работе с SQLite", error)

finally:
    if connect:
        connect.close()
        print("Соединение с SQLite закрыто")
```

---

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Да, но цикл должен идти бесконечно, пока его не остановят, а вот идея с тем, что если галочки отмечены, то их не проверяет - класс )

Comment: Что отвечает за поставку галочек при проверке ?

Comment: @OverNiko  `item.setCheckState(QtCore.Qt.Checked)`